FastAPI y SQLAlchemy: AttributeError: 'ObjetoDb' object has no attribute 'items'
Tengo este endpoint en FastAPI:
@router.post('/diarias')
async def set_diarias( request : Request, db : Session = Depends(deps.get_db), payload : dict = Depends(deps.get_payload) ):
    items : dict = await request.json()
    datos = json.loads(items["datos"])
    fecha = items["fecha"]
    for empleado in datos:
        for i,ent in enumerate(empleado["horaEntrada"]):
            hora = Horas(
                empleado = empleado.get("empleado",''),
                turno = i,
                fecha = fecha,
                horaEntrada = empleado["horaEntrada"][i],
                horaSalida = empleado["horaSalida"][i]
            )
            new = db.query( Horas ).where( Horas.fecha == fecha, Horas.empleado == empleado.get("empleado",''), Horas.turno == i)
            if new.first() is None:
                db.add( hora )
            else:
                new.update( hora )
        comentario = HorasComentarios(
            empleado = empleado.get("empleado",''),
            fecha = fecha,
            laboral = empleado.get("laboral",''),
            direccion = empleado.get("direccion",'')
        )
        newCom = db.query( HorasComentarios ).where( HorasComentarios.empleado == empleado.get("empleado",''), HorasComentarios.fecha == fecha)
        if newCom.first() is None:
            db.add( comentario )
        else:
            newCom.update( comentario )
    db.commit()

Todo funciona bien excepto en la parte del update() en comentarios y horas.
Clase HorasComentarios:
class HorasComentarios(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'horas_comentarios'
    empleado = Column(String(255), primary_key = True)
    fecha = Column(String(255), primary_key = True)
    laboral = Column(String(255))
    direccion = Column(String(255))

Clase Horas:
class Horas(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'horas'
    turno = Column(INTEGER(11), primary_key = True)
    empleado = Column(String(255), primary_key = True)
    fecha = Column(Date, primary_key = True)
    horaEntrada = Column(String(255))
    horaSalida = Column(String(255))

Si hago un print de los objetos antes de insertar/actualizar, me sale esto:
<db.Horas object at 0x000001925A018FD0>
<db.HorasComentarios object at 0x000001925A018EB0>


Bienvenido/a a [es.so]; te felicito por haber formulado muy bien tu primera pregunta :) La sintaxis de .update(), ¿de dónde la obtuviste?

@padaleiana He intentado copiar la estructura de esta respuesta, donde le pasa un modelo de la base de datos directamente al update() para actualizar la fila de la bbdd. Sé que se puede hacer .update({"clave":"valor",...}) pero me gustaría utilizar un metodo que se vea más limpio el código.

Justamente el comentario de esa respuesta menciona que el argumento de update() debería ser un iterable, porque de no ser así daría error. Lo que también podrías hacer es comparar los valores viejos y nuevos antes de actualizar tales columnas, para evitar hacer un update si es que no hubo cambios.

Tienes razón, no ví el comentario. ¿Es más eficiente comprobar los valores antes de hacer un update() aunque no haya cambiado nada?

De mi parte te diría que sí, pero sería más bien una opinión. No sé si diría que es "más eficiente", pero sí que no está mal hacer una comprobación antes de actualizar algo que realmente no cambió. Por otra parte, no olvides aceptar tu respuesta.

@padaleiana Gracias, no me dejaba aceptarla hasta 48 horas después de publicarla.

Al final lo he solucionado transformando el objeto a un diccionario antes de enviarlo al update():
@router.post('/diarias')
async def set_diarias( request : Request, db : Session = Depends(deps.get_db), payload : dict = Depends(deps.get_payload) ):
    items : dict = await request.json()
    datos = json.loads(items["datos"])
    fecha = items["fecha"]
    for empleado in datos:
        for i,ent in enumerate(empleado["horaEntrada"]):
            hora = Horas(
                empleado = empleado.get("empleado",''),
                turno = i,
                fecha = fecha,
                horaEntrada = empleado["horaEntrada"][i],
                horaSalida = empleado["horaSalida"][i]
            )
            new = db.query( Horas ).where( Horas.fecha == fecha, Horas.empleado == empleado.get("empleado",''), Horas.turno == i)
            if new.first() is None:
                db.add( hora )
            else:
                auxHor = dict(hora.__dict__) # transformo a diccionario
                auxHor.pop("_sa_instance_state", None) # elimino una clave del diccionario que no necesito
                new.update( auxHor )
        comentario = HorasComentarios(
            empleado = empleado.get("empleado",''),
            fecha = fecha,
            sandra = empleado.get("sandra",''),
            jose = empleado.get("jose",'')
        )
        newCom = db.query( HorasComentarios ).where( HorasComentarios.empleado == empleado.get("empleado",''), HorasComentarios.fecha == fecha)
        if newCom.first() is None:
            db.add( comentario )
        else:
            auxCom = dict(comentario.__dict__) # lo mismo que en Horas
            auxCom.pop("_sa_instance_state", None)
            newCom.update( auxCom )
    db.commit()

